# could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'

Tags: typescript

I have the following function

```
function pickAndTrim <T> (keys : Array<string>, object : T ) : T {
    function trim <A> (input : A) : A {
            if (typeof input === "string") {
                return input.trim();
            }
            return input;
    }
    let updates = R.pick(keys, object);
    updates = R.map(trim, updates);
    return updates;
}
```

**Note:** R is Ramda

What it's doing is that it takes an Object, picks certain keys (and values) from it, then trims any values from that resulting Object if it's a string.

The current error I'm getting is:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

How do I make typescript accept that it definitely it is a string (since I checked it with `typeof`)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't complain that "input" is not a string- "'string' not assignable to type 'A'" - I think the problem is, that in some cases TypeScript infers a function type `f: A -> string` and then you have some `let var: A = f(x)` but you can't assign a string to an A.

I'm not familiar with Rambda, but you could try a filter with a type guard:

`filter updates (x => typeof x === 'string')`

so you have a list of string and then map over that.

Or apparently Ramda has a `pickBy` function:

```
R.pickBy((val, key) => (keys.indexOf(key) >= 0) && (typeof val === 'string'), object);
```

I'm not familiar with that library and I can't seem to get type information for these functions, so it returns "any", which isn't great.

Comment: There should be a `@types/ramda` but I got rid of the error just by removing the typing. Typescript is still /shrug for me, but at least it solves what I need to for now. Ramda was having some issues with `Exclude<T, <string...` stuff, which was too confusing for me to follow

Comment: The TypeScript handbook is really good, has often helped me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html