# Type safe deep update: could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to remove the `as any` in the `update_substate` function?  It's type safe when invoking the update_state function directly so indirectly should also be safe?  These are light weight helper functions for Redux state.  I have read some of the related questions ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64200658/typescriptcould-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445464/could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated-to-string), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322109/ts2322-t-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelate)) but do not understand the solutions yet.

```
export function update_state <
    RootState,
    P1 extends keyof RootState,
    S1 extends RootState[P1],
> (root_state: RootState, path1: P1, replacement_state: S1)
{
    const current = root_state[path1]
    if (current === replacement_state) return root_state

    return {
        ...root_state,
        [path1]: replacement_state
    }
}


export function update_substate <
    RootState,
    P1 extends keyof RootState,
    S1 extends RootState[P1],
    P2 extends keyof S1,
    S2 extends S1[P2],
> (root_state: RootState, path1: P1, path2: P2, replacement_substate: S2)
{
    /**
    Without the `as any` will get the error:

    Argument of type 'RootState[P1]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'S1'.
    'S1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RootState[P1]'.
        Type 'RootState[keyof RootState]' is not assignable to type 'S1'.
        'S1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RootState[keyof RootState]'.
            Type 'RootState[string] | RootState[number] | RootState[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'S1'.
            'S1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RootState[string] | RootState[number] | RootState[symbol]'.
                Type 'RootState[string]' is not assignable to type 'S1'.
                'S1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RootState[string]'.ts(2345)
    */
    const replacement_state = update_state<S1, P2, S2>(root_state[path1] as any, path2, replacement_substate)
    return update_state(root_state, path1, replacement_state)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to make the snippet compile (without having checked its content):

1. Omit type parameter `S1`, as it is not used in `update_substate` function signature.
2. Let parameter types infer automatically, no need to declare them with `update_state<S1, P2, S2>`.
3. Update the generic constraint of `P2` to be `P2 extends keyof RootState[P1]`.

```
export function update_substate <
    RootState,
    P1 extends keyof RootState,
    P2 extends keyof RootState[P1],
    S2 extends RootState[P1][P2],
> (root_state: RootState, path1: P1, path2: P2, replacement_substate: S2)
{
    const replacement_state = update_state(root_state[path1], path2, replacement_substate)
    return update_state(root_state, path1, replacement_state)
}
```

[Live code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyWAEwEMZgB9AZxhODgB4AoOZuAJQghgGVrSAaJiwAKARjihSKAhTgBrYAE8ICNh269gAlnC5iJwKTPaceNANqiAugIB8cABRQ1lDQC5VJjXzhgSACxF3UW8oYDAAGyI0YABbAxgXGnddAEoGAG9BZjQcKjg0JChQlHgAXjgnTkTSM18YAMssuEwVewKi%20LhS7oqwyOi4kurgFN6YQtxKhKoaBibQ8ahcTO1tADoNqeGtVeZa-xFLd1CIqNj44aaAXwYbhlBIWERUDGxcfGJSSiQAIxnSehNYzqGg7ZiicQgSTSOSKZQeEH8JpCABMkOhMnkShUwNMNSsYJ0aP0hgReOAFkOFhR1gYdkczn%20wHcuK8PgOQRE3jqfhRQRRIT6Z0G01%20TOSKLSKxYORQeRO-XOQyZXTwhBowwZVSZ%203qh25-gFvVOAwuFDFGjS2gWEzVn3ITK10zZPK5xsVIuGaSuQA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy answer and solution.  It works great.  Yes I think the "Omit type parameter xyz, as it is not used in function signature" is a good smell test.